# Adding Navigation Drawer to TabHost Activity in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tabhost

I have an android app that uses legacy TabHost, its deprecated but still works fine.

Requirement is to add a sliding Navigation Drawer to the TabHost. Menu in the Nav drawer will be a combination of tabs in the tabhost plus additional items.

Can anyone provide examples of how to integrate Navigation Drawer with TabHost?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Section 3.2 in [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) article explains quite well how to implement the navigation drawer. In this example they set it up with a header and a RecyclerView, but you can really build it however you like.

I hope this helps

Comment: Your example does not include TabHost integration. I'm familiar with Navigation Drawer usage with fragments, but not with LEGACY TAB HOST.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is plenty of resources available on TabHost on Google

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear about it to you - Title clearly says integration of NavigationDrawer with TabHost class. Its about as clear as it can get.

Comment: Look up android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.